# Volley JsonObjectRequest error response code 500

Tags: android, json, http, android-volley, jsonobjectrequest

when i try to post json and take result as a json i get response code 500 error. But if i try this with string request there is no problem. I searched a lot on stackoverflow, there are other people like me having this problem but there is no up-to-date solution for this. So may anyone show me how i can do json object post request by up-to-date method(with also php side) please?

Android side:

```
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
    map.put("user", username);
    map.put("pass", password);

    JsonObjectRequest sr = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://www.example.com/example/.php?action=signin", new JSONObject(map), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject result) {

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

    }) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

            return params;
        }
    };
```

PHP side:

```
$post = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
        $user = $post['user'];
        $pass = $post['pass'];

$array = array("entrance" =>  $example);

echo json_encode($array,true);
```

Comment: 500 is a server side error  There is a error in your php code

Comment: Where is the error? I put the php code as well. Everything looks fine. :(

Comment: $array = array("entrance" =>  $example); Where is the $exaple ?? you post the full code??

Comment: It is an another another variable. I did not post the full php code. I don't think the problem is about the rest.

Comment: read php error log in apache that all i know

Comment: how can i read php error log?

Comment: Display the errors with this at begin of php file
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
and open a page in a web browser (coment the json part)

Comment: Thank u so much, we fixed the server error. Now server error has gone but there is a parse error which is about android side i guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem, there was only one element in my json object which is a jsonarray actually. After i changed jsonobjectrequest to jsonarrayrequest, the problem was solved.

Comment: How is that only one element? I can see here login and password - that's two elements, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
JSONObject map = new JSONObject(); 
map.put("user", username);
map.put("pass", password);

JsonObjectRequest sr = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://www.example.com/example/.php?action=signin", map, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject result) {
        Log.e("ServiceCall", result.toString());
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.e("ServiceCall", error.toString());
    }
});
RequestQueue mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(<Activity>.this);
mRequestQueue.add(sr);
```

> i think you have problem with your json ..and thats why at the server
>   side it throws error and server error 500 comes

Comment: check what your webservice is required in its  paramters