# VOLLEY 500 and 400 error

Tags: android, android-volley

I am not getting whats wrong with my code , I want to send a volley request with header and parameters , where parameters format will be "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" .

i am getting 400 error when i am using this code

```
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Token", "1234);
            params.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            return params;
        }
```

and getting 500 error  when i am using this code

```
@Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("Token", "1234);
        return params;
    }
```

and the whole function is

```
public void requestWithSomeHttpHeaders() {

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,"http://12.211.156.201/SOWebService/Service.asmx/GetCompany",
            new Response.Listener<String>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    System.out.println(response);

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    System.out.println(error.toString() + "--" + error.getCause());

                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.d("ERROR","error => "+error.toString());
                    // definitions.setText("check your internet connection");
                    if (error instanceof TimeoutError || error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                        System.out.println("1");
                    } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                        System.out.println("2");
                        //TODO
                    } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                        System.out.println("3");
                        //TODO
                    } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                        System.out.println("4");
                        //TODO
                    } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                        System.out.println("5");
                        //TODO
                    }
                }
            }
    )

    {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Token", token);
            return params;
        }

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            // return super.getParams();
            Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("groupName", "avd");
            params.put("userCode", "ADMIN");

            return params;
        }

    };
    queue.add(postRequest);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Volley JsonObjectRequest error response code 500](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33003260/volley-jsonobjectrequest-error-response-code-500) **take a look**

Its All About Your Json. Thats Why server Throws These Errors
Check Your URL Here 
http://pro.jsonlint.com/